# How to send a POST request to OData v4 ActionImport with SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

I would like to send a POST request to an OData v4 ActionImport. How can I achieve this in an SAPUI5 environment? I had a look at the v4 [ODataModel](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v4.ODataModel) and [ODataContextBinding](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v4.ODataContextBinding). There are methods for execute an ActionImport but i dont know how to set the body then.

Generally asking: How should I submit OData requests that should not necessarily be bound to the UI? For example, if I just want to query a value from the backend or send a file to the backend. Right now, I create an ODataContextBinding and call the execute/requestObject method but i think that this might not be the best approach (Also i cant set the request body this way). Maybe it might be better to make a direct ajax request?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I stumbled on your question because I had the exact same problem. I'm providing my solution in case it helps someone else.

```
onValidate: function(oEvent) {
   var oModel = this.getModel("reportService");
   var oActivityCreateContext = this.getCreateContext();
   var oActionODataContextBinding = oModel.bindContext("/validateActivity(...)");
   oActionODataContextBinding.setParameter("activity", oActivityCreateContext.getObject())
   oActionODataContextBinding.execute().then(
      function() {
          var oActionContext = oActionODataContextBinding.getBoundContext();
          console.table(oActionContext.getObject().value);
      }.bind(this)
   );
}
```

The model "reportService" is a sap.ui.model.odata.v4.ODataModel. The function call is unbound and is declared this way in my service.cds file:

```
action validateActivity(activity : Activities) returns many rm.ValidationMessage;
```

The oActionContext.getObject().value contains the response to my function call.

The key here is the setParameter that sets the activity on the payload. Here's what the resulting request could look like:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/api/ReportService/validateActivity
Content-Type: application/json

{"activity": {
    "activityNumber": 1,
    "report_ID": "a3558fce-76bc-49a9-ae23-bd5566fb3bc6",
    "job_code": "160",
    "learningPeriod": 1,
    "salaryAnnex": "D3",
    "workingRegion_code": "08",
    "unionName": "CSD",
    "local": "Local 123",
    "nbWeeksWorked": 8,
    "nbHourSimple": 110,
    "nbHourTimeAndHalf": 5,
    "nbHourDouble": 0,
    "sin": "111222333",
}}
```

I hope this will help others who are struggling to do this.

Regards

Comment: Hi Sylvain, thanks for your reply! I also ended up using deferred bindings and the setParameter method to set the payload.

Answer (score 1):

I also want to add some information to this topic. The post above helped me a lot to get this working along with the official [docu](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/topic/b54f7895b7594c61a83fa7257fa9d13f).

I have an action bound to an entity in my CAP service to which I want to pass a parameter coming from the UI inputs.

My UI5 view is bound to the entity.

`this.getView().bindElement("/MyEntity(0)");`

Calling the action is now quite easy using the hereby created binding in any given event handler.

`const bindingContext = this.getView().`

`const oAction = this.getView().getModel().bindContext( "MyNameSpace.myAction(...)", bindingContext );`

`oAction.setParameter("myActionParameter", someVarFilledFromUI);`

`oAction.execute().then( function (result) { }, function (oError) { } );`

If you wonder where to find the namespace, open the $metadata of your CAP service. You can find it in attribute namespace of the *Schema* element following *edmx:DataServices*. Also I when I added the .srv. it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This post helped me heaps, but I was still stuck calling bound actions/functions from a CAP app.

Turns out you need to pass the complete path of the service for it to resolve the action.  The other thing is that as this is a deferred call "rfresh is silently ignored" as per the doco https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/topic/b54f7895b7594c61a83fa7257fa9d13f

So I had to chain a promise and in my case bind the parent control to refresh the table control.

```
    let path = "/EntityName(" + match[1] + ")/fullnamespace.srv.ServiceName.boundActionName(...)";
let oActionODataContextBinding = this.getModel().bindContext(path);

let parentControl = oEvent.getSource().getParent().getParent();
            let refreshModel = () =>  {
                this.refresh();
            };

oActionODataContextBinding.execute().then((response) => {
  // Handler Code
}).then(refreshModel.bind(parentControl));
```